# Fill ggplot2 histogram by two criteria

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have some data (`x`) I'd like to plot as a histogram. There are two sample types (`s`), and each sample was collected in two different ways (`r`).

I would like to plot them as a stacked histogram filled by both `s` and `r` -- the best way to do it would be to facet them as per my my last example, but I am space-limited.

I can plot the data filled by `s` using a single `geom_histogram`. I can plot two `geom_histogram`s to plot the different `r`. I don't know how to make the different geoms stack though. I haven't figured out how to fill them, but [ggnewscale](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale) is probably an option.

I'd like to choose fills such as (for example) `s` == red, blue, and `r` == light, dark of the respective `s` colour.

Any suggestions?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)

x <-           c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,2,2,-2,-2,-2,3,3,-3,-3,4,-4, 8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,10,10,10,6,6,6,11,11,5,5,12,4)
r <- as.factor(c(1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2, 1, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2, 1, 1, 2,2,2, 2, 2,2, 2, 1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2, 2, 1,1,2, 1,1))
s <- c(rep.int("a", 25), rep.int("b", 25))

figsd <- tibble(x,r,s)
  
figsd %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = s), binwidth = 1, position = "stack") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5))
```

[image]

```r
figsd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(data = . %>% filter(r == 1), aes(fill = s), binwidth = 1,alpha = 0.5, position = "stack") +
  geom_histogram(data = . %>% filter(r != 1), aes(fill = s), binwidth = 1,alpha = 0.5, position = "stack") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5))
```

[image]

```r
figsd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = r), binwidth = 1,position = "stack") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5)) +
  facet_grid(s ~ .)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You could use an interaction: `ggplot(figsd, aes(x)) + geom_histogram(aes(fill = interaction(r, s)), binwidth = 1, position = "stack") + scale_fill_manual(values = c('1.a' = 'lightblue', '1.b' = 'darkblue', '2.a' = 'pink', '2.b' = 'darkred'))`

Comment: @alistaire this is exactly what I want. `interaction` is a new function to me. Thanks. If you want to add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an interaction between the two groupings and pass that to the `fill` aesthetic:

```r
library(ggplot2)

figsd <- data.frame(
    x = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,2,2,-2,-2,-2,3,3,-3,-3,4,-4, 8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,10,10,10,6,6,6,11,11,5,5,12,4),
    r = as.factor(c(1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2, 1, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2, 1, 1, 2,2,2, 2, 2,2, 2, 1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2, 2, 1,1,2, 1,1)),
    s = c(rep.int("a", 25), rep.int("b", 25))
)


ggplot(figsd, aes(x, fill = interaction(r, s))) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(
        '1.a' = 'lightblue', 
        '1.b' = 'darkblue', 
        '2.a' = 'pink', 
        '2.b' = 'darkred'
    )) + 
    labs(fill = 'group')
```

[image: histogram of interaction]

Levels here don't inherently mean anything, so you'll likely want to set fill colors deliberately to show relationships.

Also note that `interaction()` doesn't scale well, for whatever reason—if you're dealing with 100k rows, `paste()` will be considerably faster even though `interaction()` is more semantically correct in terms of what you're trying to display.

Comment: My real data isn't much bigger than the example, so it's fine. I rejiggered the factor and legend ordering to make it better, and redid the colours to match what I had in my head (which wasn't necessarily what I said)

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the comment of @alistaire.

Redid ordering and colouring to make it a little better.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tibble)

x <-           c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,2,2,2,-2,-2,-2,3,3,-3,-3,4,-4, 8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,7,7,7,10,10,10,6,6,6,11,11,5,5,12,4)
r <- as.factor(c(1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2, 1, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2, 1, 1, 2,2,2, 2, 2,2, 2, 1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2, 1, 2, 2,2,2,2, 2, 1,1,2, 1,1))
s <- c(rep.int("a", 25), rep.int("b", 25))

figsd <- tibble(x,r,s)

figsd %>%  mutate(r = factor(r, levels=c(2, 1))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=x)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = interaction(r,s)), binwidth = 1, position = "stack")+ 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("1.a","2.a","1.b","2.b"),
                    values = c('1.a' = 'lightblue', '1.b' = 'pink', '2.a' = 'darkblue', '2.b' = 'darkred'),
                    labels = c("1.a","2.a","1.b","2.b")
                   ) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>